# Network policy not working with daemonset pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-networkpolicy, calico, daemonset

Is a network policy applicable to pods of a daemonset? I have a default deny network policy for all ingress and egress for all pods. However, it does not seem to seem to be applied for pods belonging to the daemonset.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`netpol` is applicable for the pods spawned under `daemonset`. For `netpol` they are just pods like the one deployed by deployments or `rs`.

If you do the description of the `netpol` you provided, it says its applicable for `namespace=default`.

```
Name:         default-deny
Namespace:    default
Created on:   2021-07-21 17:59:56 -0500 CDT
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Spec:
  PodSelector:     <none> (Allowing the specific traffic to all pods in this namespace)
  Allowing ingress traffic:
    <none> (Selected pods are isolated for ingress connectivity)
  Allowing egress traffic:
    <none> (Selected pods are isolated for egress connectivity)
  Policy Types: Ingress, Egress
```

and `netpol` is a namespaced resource:

```
NAME                              SHORTNAMES   APIVERSION                             NAMESPACED   KIND
networkpolicies                   netpol       networking.k8s.io/v1                   true         NetworkPolicy
```

This means your `daemonset` is created under some different namespace.

Here is one example:

Created a daemon set:

```
kubectl get pod -n jackops  -o wide
NAME          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP               NODE    NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
curl          1/1     Running   0          53m   10.233.75.51     node2   <none>           <none>
dummy-2b9qv   1/1     Running   0          50m   10.233.75.4      node2   <none>           <none>
dummy-tx9rl   1/1     Running   0          50m   10.233.102.149   node1   <none>           <none>
```

Verified that curl is working without netpol:

```
k exec -it curl -n jackops   -- curl -m 5  10.233.75.4 -I
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.23.3
Date: Tue, 07 Feb 2023 17:13:05 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 615
Last-Modified: Tue, 13 Dec 2022 15:53:53 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "6398a011-267"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Applied the below netpol:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny
  namespace: jackops
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
```

Now, the connection is not going through:

```
k exec -it curl -n jackops   -- curl -m 5  10.233.75.4 -I
curl: (28) Connection timed out after 5001 milliseconds
command terminated with exit code 28
```

About, knowing who is the parent of an object:

```
kubectl get pod -n jackops  dummy-2b9qv -ojsonpath='{.metadata.ownerReferences}'
[{"apiVersion":"apps/v1","blockOwnerDeletion":true,"controller":true,"kind":"DaemonSet","name":"dummy","uid":"cba5c840-672a-4ad8-830f-03993e32117a"}]
```

Comment: Could you please provide documentation that supports what you are saying here? Can you provide a working example of a network-policy applied to a daemonset that blocks some traffic?

Comment: @jackops deployments, replica sets, daemon sets, etc., are different kinds of abstraction built on top of the pod; each of these objects differently controls the behavior of the pod. But in the end, they spawn pods and manage them using their respective controllers. With this, if you read the `kubectl describe netpol` output, you will find `Allowing the specific traffic to all pods in this namespace.`  statement is making much more sense. This is really fundamentals; you can find it over kuberentes official docs. Anyway, I have added an example,

Comment: I downvoted because IMO the answer was not complete (see above). Also, if a pod runs with the `hostNetwork` flag set to `true`, then network-policies will not be applied to the pod. This happens because with that flag the pod is attached to the host network adapter. I think this may help debugging issues with network policies.